# MYSQL Query to SELECT row based on a value (if exists) otherwise return data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CATALOG:
------------------------------------
| itemID    | itemCode  | itemName |
------------------------------------

ORDER:
----------------------------------------------
| orderID   | itemID_FK | itemPrice | etc... |
----------------------------------------------
```

I want to select `itemName`, `itemPrice`, `itemCode` etc by using a `join` on both tables.

So far so good; however, the row corresponding to a given `itemID` in `CATALOG` may not exist in the `ORDER` table. In which case, I want to fall back on using `itemName`, `itemCode` from the first table `CATALOG`.

Is this possible using MYSQL in a single (compound) statement?

**EDIT:**
Here's a sample table

```
CATALOG:
------------------------------------
| itemID    | itemCode  | itemName |
------------------------------------
|  1        |  89873232 | Oats     |
|  2        |  32849392 | Beer     |
------------------------------------

ORDER:
----------------------------------------------
| orderID   | itemID_FK | itemPrice | etc... |
----------------------------------------------
| 213232    |  2        |  3.99     |  ...   |
----------------------------------------------
```

I use the following query to retrieve complete data about an item:

```
SELECT itemID, itemName, itemPrice FROM CATALOG
INNER JOIN ORDER
ON itemID = itemID_FK
WHERE itemID = %d
```

I need this join because `CATALOG` will not contain price which is obtained from `ORDER`. If I use `itemID=1` there would not be a corresponding entry in `ORDER` table and the query would fail. I want it to retrieve at least `itemName` if there is no entry for the item in `ORDER`

Comment: What do you currently join on? Can you give your current query? If you do `...FROM CATALOG LEFT JOIN ORDER ON CATALOG.itemID=ORDER.itemID_FK` then you'll always get rows from `ORDER` for each row in `CATALOG`, an if it can't find it you'll have `NULL` in that column.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and an example of the resultset you're after?

Comment: Added a sample table and more info. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the two tables, so you will always have data corresponding to the table on the LEFT side of the JOIN:

```
SELECT C.itemName, C.itemCode, O.itemPrice, ...
FROM CATALOG as C
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER AS O ON C.itemID = O.itemID_FK
```

All the O.s in the above selection will turn up as NULL if the item from the `CATALOG` does not exist in `ORDERS`.

Comment: The `OUTER` keyword is redundant. A `LEFT JOIN` is implicitly *outer*